# how PHP password_hash() determine using which algorithm by PHP_DEFAULT?

Tags: php, password-protection, password-hash

I feel very confuse when reading the PHP doc at
http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php
**PASSWORD_DEFAULT (integer)**
The default algorithm to use for hashing if no algorithm is provided. This may change in newer PHP releases when newer, stronger hashing algorithms are supported.

How I know my installation use which algorithm?
can I know it from the phpinfo()?
can I control the default?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-get-info.php

Comment: It is a little confusing at first glance, but if you also read http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php it may help you understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need to worry about which algorithm is used by default. The leading four characters of the `password_hash()` result denote which algorithm was used. When you use `password_verify()` it will determine the algorithm automatically.

Comment: Just a note, as manual says: `. Therefore you should be aware that the length of the resulting hash can change. Therefore, if you use PASSWORD_DEFAULT you should store the resulting hash in a way that can store more than 60 characters (255 is the recomended width).`

Answer (score 0):

> How I know my installation use which algorithm?

Look in the manual.

From the page you referenced:

> Values for this constant:
>
> - PHP 5.5.0 - PASSWORD_BCRYPT

---

> can I know it from the phpinfo()?

No (well, other than using that as the mechanism to learn the version of PHP you are using and then cross-referencing with the manual).

---

> can I control the default?

Not without forking PHP and compiling your own version.

Comment: Quentin, might also be useful to add something about password_needs_rehash() into this answer

Comment: You could also just hash a dummy string and read the first few chars of the result to determine the used algo instead of check against the php version